# inverse of a non decreasing step function, defined as an inf

Tags: real-analysis

$g : \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ is a non-decreasing and right continuous step function such that $g(x)=0$ for all $x \leq 0$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x \geq 1$. Let us define $g^{-1}(y) = \inf { \{x : x \geq 0, \ g(x) \geq y\} }$

Then, is it a continuous function, right/left continuous or neither ?

Where I'm specifically having a problem is the [$g(x) \geq y$]  part. I do not understand what this means in this context.

Edit: it has been pointed out to me that the function $g$ is not defined in $(0,1)$ so the question is incorrect. So please just assume that function is well defined but however many steps the question says exists, exist between $(0,1)$.

Comment: Did you have to use $g^{-1}{(y)}$? It's not self-evident that your function is really the inverse of $g(x)$. So why not use for example $h(x)$ instead in the question?

Comment: Did you mean "$g(x)=1$ for all $x\geq 0$" or is $R=\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,1]$?

Comment: i meant g(x)=1 for all x≥0

Comment: What's this got to do with economics? lol

Comment: I see. Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Try it on the example $ g(x) = \begin{cases}
          0, & x < 0,\\
          1, &  x \geq 0
          \end{cases} $ and follow the definition to see what is happening in this definition.  You should be able to explicitly calculate $ g^{-1} $.  In particular, calculate the five cases $ g^{-1}(x) $ for $ x < 0 $, $ x = 0 $, $ 0 < x < 1 $, $ x = 1 $, and $ x > 1 $.

Comment: Your example doesn't have $g(0) = 0$ like in the question.

Comment: Maybe should be $x<1$ and $x \geq 1$ in your definition of $g(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand. I think whoever edited the question rewrote the definition of the inverse function and Using it on an easier example given by jake helped me understand the definition.

Eg  When $y=-1$, then $g^{-1}(-1)=\inf\{x : x\ge0, g(x) \ge -1\}$ so we just take $g(x)$ as $0$ since no value of $x$ maps to $y= -1$ under $g$.

Now the solution. Can someone please confirm this

lets assume there are steps in this function for simplicity

```
    $g(x) = 0$ if $x <= 0$

    $g(x) = a$ if $0 < x < (1-e)$  where 0<a,e<1

    $g(x) = 1$ if $(1-e) < x$
```

this "e" is important since it is given that $g$ is right continuous and $g(x) =1$ for $x\ge 1$ This means the beginning of the step should lie to the left of 1

we then calculate inverse and if $y$ belongs to (-$\infty$, a] then $g^{-1}(y)= 0$

for $y$ belongs to $( a, 1], g^{-1}(y)= (1-e)$

For $y$ greater than $1$, no $g(x)$ exists that can satisfy the inequality so inf is a null set.

Clearly, the inverse function is left continuous. Ideally, like jake said, this should be split in 5 cases but since it came out to be same ive shortened it